# How To Set Dynamic Meta Keyword & Author In Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, metadata, next.js13, app-route

I tried this but it's not working, In official documentation they only given example of dynamic title and description, plzz anyone help me.

I Tried This:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: {
    default: 'HealthCare Biodiversity',
    template: '%s | HealthCare Biodiversity'
  },
  description: {
    default: 'The Dynamic & Powerful Blog',
    template: '%s | HealthCare Biodiversity'
  },
  referrer: 'origin-when-cross-origin',
  keywords: {
    default: ['Next.js', 'React', 'JavaScript'],
    template: [ '%s']
  },
  authors: {
    default: [{ name: 'Seb' }],
    template: [  { name: '%s' }]
  }
}
```

This code is on my layout.js of new app router.

I mentioned what I tried and what I'm expecting. plzz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. I have experimented with adding the **keywords** and **author** metadata to my Next.js 13.4 project app (using the app router).

Within the `metadata` variable object, the `keywords` property needs to be defined as an array of strings, rather than an object (as seen in your posted example). And also, the `authors` property also needs to be an array, but of objects with certain properties; `name`, and `url`, where both those properties are optional. See example snippet below:

```js
export const metadata = {
  title: {
    default: 'HealthCare Biodiversity',
    template: '%s | HealthCare Biodiversity'
  },
  description: {
    default: 'The Dynamic & Powerful Blog',
    template: '%s | HealthCare Biodiversity'
  },
  referrer: 'origin-when-cross-origin',
  keywords: ['Next.js', 'React', 'JavaScript', 'HealthCare', 'Biodiversity'],
  authors: [
    { name: 'Seb', url: 'https://github.com/arshcode' }
  ]
}
```

Documentation source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#basic-fields